mapbox/maplibre: Why are two fonts automatically requested？
my style:
"glyphs": "../resource/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"

////////////////

"text-font": [ "Open Sans Regular"]

I only set up one font file, but requested two fonts
enter image description here
I hope “resource/fonts/Open%20Sans%20Regular/0-255.pbf”
but：“resource/fonts/Open%20Sans%20Regular,Arial%20Unicode%20MS%20Regular/0-255.pbf”

"text-font" Defaults to Open Sans Regular,Arial Unicode MS Regular
